# solving a problem given on the hackerearth platform

Tags: c++

I am solving a problem given on the hackerearth platform. I have the logic and my python solution got accepted right away. The issue with cpp code which is below

```
#include <iostream>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ll int n,m;
    cin>>m>>n;
    ll int a[m];
    for(ll int i=0;i<m;i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    ll int b[n+1]={0};
    b[0]=1;
    for(ll int e:a){
        for(ll int i=e;i<=n;i++){
            b[i]+=b[i-e];
        }
    }

    cout<<(b[n]%(1000000000+7));
}
```

Don't check the logic. It's correct. The problem is instead of getting 585888586 I am getting -250167331. I have to take the mod with 10^9+7 which I have taken. The negative answer can't come. the problem is happening due to data type issue. Same code in python is getting accepted. What's wrong here.

I am new to cpp so I might have committed silly mistake.

This is the link to the problem

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/accomodation-a5c006f3/

Comment: `ll int a[m];` is not legal in standard c++

Comment: then how to declare that long long int array in c++ 14?

Comment: `std::vector` is the standard c++ way.

Comment: but I want to use array. Are you saying that in c++ long int arrays are non existent

Comment: The size of an array is a compile time constant. Some compilers allow for the `c`  VLA as an extension.

Comment: You're overflowing. You're supposed to use the identity `(a + b) mod m == ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m`. You didn't notice this in Python because Python has arbitrarily large integers, which lets you ignore the entire point of this exercise.

Comment: @molbdnilo even in that case how will this modulo effect lead to negative output. This is certainly a data type issue. I am using long long int still the values are not fitting in the long int variable

Comment: ***how will this modulo effect lead to negative output*** Overflow can wrap around.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. You try to use a C array where you *should* be using a `std::vector`.

Comment: @NikhilRathore The problem is that you're not using the "modulo effect", which means that you're causing overflow (which has undefined behaviour and makes the program invalid). It's not a data type issue, it's a logic issue.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you give give the corrected block of code of mine is wrong. What should I change